# Set column width in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Searching for this topic and found a solution but doesn't work for me
The code I am working on (part of it like that)

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

The line of setting the max colwidth: I tried to put this line before the df line and another try after the df line but the output still the same.. Any ideas?

Comment: can you show what is happening with u exactly?

Comment: I am using Jupyter Notebook and the column width is only the half of my screen. The dataframe is only one series and I need to expand to fill the width of the screen.

Comment: The column is not expanding at all? Or it's not expanding as you wish?

Comment: The column is not expanding at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting the others parameters also like:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000, 'display.width', 1000, 'display.max_rows',1000)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the same problem is still there. I am confused.

Comment: have you already tried pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)?

Comment: I found -1 is deprecated so I used None instead but the same problem `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)`

Comment: The columns are not expanding at all in Jupyter Lab at least